# how to get title of pdf file using itext in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How can I get titles in pdf document using itext and java?

I have used `pdfTextExtractor` but it returns all contents of a page.

Comment: who downvoted it? look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698460/get-and-set-metadata-for-itext-pdf-document)

Comment: i have already seen this but it's about writer . I want to how can read from an existing file

Comment: I was searching the answer a couple days ago, but I didn't find anything

Comment: Are the titles in your PDF marked as titles? In other words: is your PDF tagged or does it have outlines? If not: how do you suppose a machine can know what's a title and what's not? Your question is unanswerable in its current state. Please complete your question.

Comment: I don't know its just a regular pdf I picked up

Comment: as I think titles are usually larger in font size than rest . so can I track them according to font size

Comment: thank you everyone found a solution

Comment: If you found a solution post it here so that everybody can benefit from it. If you post it you can accept it as the answer...