# Get custom metadata for itext 7 pdf document

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I used the link given below for getting metadata in itext 5 using: [Get and set metadata for itext pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698460/get-and-set-metadata-for-itext-pdf-document)

Currently, i can get metadata in itext7 too using the snippet:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
info.getAuthor();
info.getCreator();
info.getProducer();
```

I don't know how to get custom properties using the same.
I can set custom metadata using:

```
pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo().setMoreInfo("Test", "test");
```

How to get this value programatically without hard coding the key name?
Also, is there a way to get these metadata values (including custom metadata) without actually writing:

```
getAuthor, getCreator, etc?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No worries, got the answer.
Didn't realize earlier that:

```
PdfDictionary map = info.getPdfObject();
```

returns map type object. Parsed the map to get all the key-value pairs including the custom properties.
Below is the full code snippet:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocumentInfo;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class GetInfo {

    public static final String SRC = "hello.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(SRC);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new GetInfo().manipulatePdf(SRC);
    }

    public void manipulatePdf(String src) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
        PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
        PdfDictionary map = info.getPdfObject();
        for(Entry<PdfName, PdfObject> entry : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey().getValue() + " - " + entry.getValue() );
        }
        pdfDoc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iText 7.0.8+ you can get a pdf metadata map this way.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
//get metadata map
PdfDictionary catalog = pdfDoc.getTrailer();
PdfDictionary map = catalog.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Info);
for (Map.Entry<PdfName, PdfObject> entry : map.entrySet()) {
 System.out.println(entry.getKey().getValue() + " - " + entry.getValue());
}
pdfDoc.close();
```

You can set custom metadata using:

```
 map.put(new PdfName("test"), new PdfString("test"));
```