# Modify pdf metadata XMP

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xmp

I would like to modify existing metadata XMP in pdf using iText or similar library.

I get xmp string by *com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getMetadata()*
Below we have example xmp

```
<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.2-c001 63.139439, 2010/09/27-13:37:26        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
         <dc:identifier>10.1016/j.aipprr.2017.03.003</dc:identifier>
         <dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Prólogo</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:title>
         <dc:creator>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>Rolando Díaz-Loving</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:creator>
         <dc:description>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Acta de Investigación Psicológica , 7 (2017) 2559. doi:10.1016/j.aipprr.2017.03.003</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:description>
         <dc:publisher>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li>Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, Facultad de Psicología</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </dc:publisher>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/3.0/">
         <prism:aggregationType>journal</prism:aggregationType>
         <prism:publicationName>Acta de Investigación Psicológica </prism:publicationName>
         <prism:copyright>© 2017 Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, Facultad de Psicología. This is an open access article under the CC BY-NC-ND license (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/).</prism:copyright>
         <prism:issn>2007-4719</prism:issn>
         <prism:volume>7</prism:volume>
         <prism:number>1</prism:number>
         <prism:coverDisplayDate>April 2017</prism:coverDisplayDate>
         <prism:pageRange>2559</prism:pageRange>
         <prism:startingPage>2559</prism:startingPage>
         <prism:doi>10.1016/j.aipprr.2017.03.003</prism:doi>
         <prism:url>http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aipprr.2017.03.003</prism:url>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:crossmark="http://crossref.org/crossmark/1.0/">
         <crossmark:MajorVersionDate>2010-04-23</crossmark:MajorVersionDate>
         <crossmark:CrossmarkDomainExclusive>true</crossmark:CrossmarkDomainExclusive>
         <crossmark:DOI>10.1016/j.aipprr.2017.03.003</crossmark:DOI>
         <crossmark:CrossMarkDomains>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>elsevier.com</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>sciencedirect.com</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crossmark:CrossMarkDomains>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:jav="http://www.niso.org/schemas/jav/1.0/">
         <jav:journal_article_version>VoR</jav:journal_article_version>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:pdfx="http://ns.adobe.com/pdfx/1.3/">
         <pdfx:ElsevierWebPDFSpecifications>6.5</pdfx:ElsevierWebPDFSpecifications>
         <pdfx:doi>10.1016/j.aipprr.2017.03.003</pdfx:doi>
         <pdfx:robots>noindex</pdfx:robots>
         <pdfx:CrossmarkMajorVersionDate>2010-04-23</pdfx:CrossmarkMajorVersionDate>
         <pdfx:CrossmarkDomainExclusive>true</pdfx:CrossmarkDomainExclusive>
         <pdfx:CrossMarkDomainsↂ005B1ↂ005D>sciencedirect.com</pdfx:CrossMarkDomainsↂ005B1ↂ005D>
         <pdfx:CrossMarkDomainsↂ005B2ↂ005D>elsevier.com</pdfx:CrossMarkDomainsↂ005B2ↂ005D>
         <pdfx:CrossMarkDomains>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>sciencedirect.com</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>elsevier.com</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </pdfx:CrossMarkDomains>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
         <xmp:CreatorTool>Elsevier</xmp:CreatorTool>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2017-05-25T20:23:38-05:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2017-05-03T16:07:41Z</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2017-05-25T20:23:38-05:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmpRights="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/">
         <xmpRights:Marked>True</xmpRights:Marked>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
         <pdf:Trapped>True</pdf:Trapped>
         <pdf:Producer>Acrobat Distiller 9.0.0 (Windows)</pdf:Producer>
         <pdf:Keywords/>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:9d0cc73b-66d9-4125-9685-0f38e1653c8b</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:a666df63-92f4-44d1-8d4a-4a61bc95b979</xmpMM:InstanceID>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:ali="http://www.niso.org/schemas/ali/1.0/">
         <ali:license_ref>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <ali:uri>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/</ali:uri>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </ali:license_ref>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>                      
<?xpacket end="w"?>
```

And now I would like to modify `<xmp:ModifyDate>2017-05-25T20:23:38-05:00</xmp:ModifyDate>` with current timestamp but i actually dont know how to do it without literally string parsing. Is there any library allowing modify xmp?

Comment: You can't and shouldn't control the modification date. iText changes that date for you automatically based on the time of the clock of your computer whenever you manipulate the file.

Comment: It was just example, i would like modify also other properties

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? iText 5 and iText 7 are quite different.

Comment: I'm using iText 5.5.11

Comment: In that case, can I close the question as a duplicate of [Get and set metadata for itext pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698460/get-and-set-metadata-for-itext-pdf-document)? There is an XMP library integrated inside iText. Why are you asking for a different library? See http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/xml/xmp/package-frame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I used  XmpReader.replaceNode from iText library.